# A .Add method that adds user input to an existing list

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, list, methods

I am trying to create an Add method that allows the user to enter a team which will then be added to `list<string> teams`, it will then display the lists contents. It need to have the following clauses, if Colchester is enter it puts out No and if the contents of the list reach 10 then nothing else is added and an error is returned.

```
 public FootballTeams(){ }

    List<string> teams;
    public void ListInit()
    {
        teams = new List<string>(10);
        teams.Add("Everton");
        teams.Add("Liverpool");
        teams.Add("Arsenal");
        teams.Add("Manchester United");
        teams.Add("West Ham United");
    }

  public void AddTeams()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a team to be added: ");
        string userinput = Console.ReadLine();

        if (userinput == "Colchester")
        {
            Console.Write("NOT ALLOWED");
        }
        else if (teams.Count < 10)
        {
            teams.Add(userinput);
            foreach (var item in teams)
                Console.Write(item.ToString() + " ");
        }
        else
            Console.Write("You entered something else....");
    }
```

In the code I have the list is set to a max of 10.
In the method add teams an error springs up at `(teams.Add(userinput))` saying cannot implicitly convert type void to bool and I have zero idea of how to get the error to crop up when the contents of the list reach 10. I am also assuming that the Colchester bit is correct.

**UPDATE**
It now looks like this:

```
      public void AddTeams()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a team to be added: ");
        string userinput = Console.ReadLine();

     if (teams.Count < 10)
         {
             if (userinput != "Colchester")
             {
                 teams.Add(userinput);
                 foreach (var item in teams)
                     Console.Write(item.ToString() + " ");
             }

             else

                 Console.Write("NOT ALLOWED");
         }
            else
                Console.Write("MAXIMUM LIMIT REACHED");
        }
```

However I have discovered that Colchester is still added to the list, any ideas on how to stop this? Also when more than 10 teams are entered the message  “MAXIMUM NUMBER REACHED” should display?

Note-I am a new to C#, I know my code sucks :)

Comment: I take it that your teacher is not a Colchester fan?

Comment: @PreetSangha He just has some strange hate for them:P

Comment: The code actually isn't too bad, a few extraneous pieces (like the call to ToString) but otherwise, pretty good for someone who is new to the framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting the void to bool conversion error is that the "Add" method of System.Collections.Generic.List does not return anything, thus it can not be used as the conditional expression of an if statement.

Also, lists do not have fixed size like arrays, so you wouldn't even get an exception if your "limit" of 10 was reached. (You would get an IndexOutOfRange exception if you did use a size 10 array).

King King's answer provides the code that will do what you asked for in the other part of your question. The error message at the end could definitely be more descriptive.

Side note, since you know the list is of type "string", why bother calling ToString, it would have been called by the runtime if it wasn't a string anyways.

To answer your edit, the check for "Colchester" should come first, the code is entering the first if (because the count is less than 10) and doesn't even check the name. You could also nest the check for "Colchester" inside the count check. The nesting approach is probably "technically" better, but both will work.

To answer the second edit, replace "You entered something else" with "MAXIMUM NUMBER REACHED", to ensure that this message is displayed even if the item that would exceed the limit is "Colchester", make the check for "Colchester" nested in the count check (otherwise the "Colchester" check will take precedence).

Approach 1 (not nested):

```
   if (input == "Colchester)
      ... (display error)
   else if (list.Count < 10)
      ... (add and print)
   else
      ... (display different error)
```

Approach 2 (nested):

```
   if (list.Count < 10)
   {
      if (input != "Colchester")
      {
         ... (add and print)
      }
      else
         ... (display error)
   }
   else
      ... (display other error)
```

Comment: How do I make it nested?

Comment: It does allot thanks, just getting an error on that first else saying it is invalid

Comment: Make sure to put braces around the statements between the if and the else (assuming there is more than 1).

You can only not use braces if there is exactly one statement after the if/else if/else. I didn't include them because I was typing fast.

Comment: Just managed to figure it out before I saw your update :P, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if (teams.Count < 10){
    teams.Add(userinput);
    foreach (var item in teams)
      Console.Write(item.ToString() + " ");
} else if (userinput == "Colchester") Console.Write("NOT ALLOWED");
else Console.Write("You enter something else....");
```

Note that the logic of your code is not good (the message printed does not make much sense).